# How to remove the tab control buttons in a Netbeans application

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

After two days of back and forth, I was finally able to remove the "Scroll Documents Left", "Scroll Documents Right" buttons in the application.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If someone needs to do it as well I used a combination of the following two sites 
http://w.planetnetbeans.org/topic63272.html 
https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/programmatically_setting_multirow_tabs

My problem now is that the buttons only disappear the first time I run the application after "Cleaning the project" (right click -> clean). All the subsequent times I run the project the buttons still there.

Any idea what I could be missing?

EDIT:
I found a workaround, unfortunately this removes the persistence of the windows, and I am not sure if there might be some other side effects.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    //find the local folder that must be deleted
    try {
        FileObject rootFolder = PersistenceManager.getDefault().getRootLocalFolder();
        if (null != rootFolder) {
                for( FileObject fo : rootFolder.getChildren() ) {
                    if( PersistenceManager.COMPS_FOLDER.equals( fo.getName() ) )
                        continue; //do not delete settings files
                    fo.delete();
                }
        }
    } catch( IOException ioE ) {
        ErrorManager.getDefault().notify( ErrorManager.INFORMATIONAL, ioE );
    }

    UIManager.put(TabDisplayer.EDITOR_TAB_DISPLAYER_UI_CLASS_ID, NoTabsTabDisplayerUI.class.getName());        
}
```

Any ideas on how this could be done without having to give up the persistence of the windows?

Comment: I just found out that resetting the windows from the Menu "Windows" -> "Reset Windows" also make the buttons disappear again. Any idea why the windows need to be reset to make the control buttons disappear again?